IOS Core Motion App - Getting Sensor Data On the Debug Console, but No GUI Display (iphone)
Good morning.
I wrote an IOS app, to gather data from my iphone gyros and accelerometers.
I am able to get the data, which I can print on the XCode debug console.
However, nothing shows on the iphone screen, and when I debug the view hierarchy, I only get a black screen (no GUI hierarchy available).
I have no clue why this is happening.
I'm hoping someone can help identify what my error is.
The code I developed first was not using a storyboard, then I used a storyboard: same result. The GUI simply is not showing.
Of course, I gave the authorization for my app to access sensor data, because I can see it flowing in the debug console of XCode.

//
//  CoreMotionDemoApp.swift
//  CoreMotionDemo
//
//  Created by Julien Esposito on 6/18/24.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Create a window instance
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        
        // Set the root view controller to an instance of ViewController
        let viewController = ViewController()
        window?.rootViewController = viewController
        
        // Make the window visible
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        print("Application did finish launching")
        return true
    }
}

# MotionManager.swift  
import CoreMotion

class MotionManager {
    static let shared = MotionManager()
    private let motionManager = CMMotionManager()

    private init() {
        print("MotionManager initialized")
    }

    func startAccelerometerUpdates() {
        print("Checking accelerometer availability")
        if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable {
            motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = 0.1
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue()) { [weak self] data, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Accelerometer error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else { return }
                self?.processAccelerometerData(data: data)
            }
            print("Accelerometer updates started")
        } else {
            print("Accelerometer not available")
        }
    }

    func startGyroUpdates() {
        print("Checking gyroscope availability")
        if motionManager.isGyroAvailable {
            motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.1
            motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue()) { [weak self] data, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("Gyroscope error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
                guard let data = data else { return }
                self?.processGyroscopeData(data: data)
            }
            print("Gyroscope updates started")
        } else {
            print("Gyroscope not available")
        }
    }

    private func processAccelerometerData(data: CMAccelerometerData) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .accelerometerDataUpdated, object: nil, userInfo: ["data": data])
        }
    }

    private func processGyroscopeData(data: CMGyroData) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .gyroscopeDataUpdated, object: nil, userInfo: ["data": data])
        }
    }
}

# NotificationNameExtensions.swift  
//
//  NotificationNameExtensions.swift
//  CoreMotionDemo
//
//  Created by Julien Esposito on 6/19/24.
//

// NotificationNameExtensions.swift
import Foundation

extension Notification.Name {
    static let accelerometerDataUpdated = Notification.Name("accelerometerDataUpdated")
    static let gyroscopeDataUpdated = Notification.Name("gyroscopeDataUpdated")
}


# ViewController.swift  
import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var accelerometerData: CMAccelerometerData?
    var gyroscopeData: CMGyroData?

    var accelerationXLabel: UILabel!
    var accelerationYLabel: UILabel!
    var accelerationZLabel: UILabel!
    var rotationRateXLabel: UILabel!
    var rotationRateYLabel: UILabel!
    var rotationRateZLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set a clear background color to ensure visibility
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        // Call the setupLabels method to add and configure UI elements
        setupLabels()

        print("Starting MotionManager updates")
        MotionManager.shared.startAccelerometerUpdates()
        MotionManager.shared.startGyroUpdates()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateAccelerometerData), name: .accelerometerDataUpdated, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(updateGyroscopeData), name: .gyroscopeDataUpdated, object: nil)

        print("ViewController loaded")
    }

    func setupLabels() {
        // Create and configure UILabels
        accelerationXLabel = createLabel(text: "Acceleration X: ")
        accelerationYLabel = createLabel(text: "Acceleration Y: ")
        accelerationZLabel = createLabel(text: "Acceleration Z: ")
        rotationRateXLabel = createLabel(text: "Rotation Rate X: ")
        rotationRateYLabel = createLabel(text: "Rotation Rate Y: ")
        rotationRateZLabel = createLabel(text: "Rotation Rate Z: ")

        // Create and configure a UIStackView
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [
            accelerationXLabel, accelerationYLabel, accelerationZLabel,
            rotationRateXLabel, rotationRateYLabel, rotationRateZLabel
        ])
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 8
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // Add the stack view to the main view
        view.addSubview(stackView)

        // Configure auto layout constraints for the stack view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        ])

        print("Labels have been set up")
        print(stackView) // Print stackView details to debug
    }

    func createLabel(text: String) -> UILabel {
        // Create a UILabel and configure its properties
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = text
        label.textColor = .black
        label.backgroundColor = .white
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        print("Label created: \(text)") // Print label creation
        return label
    }

    @objc func updateAccelerometerData(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let data = notification.userInfo?["data"] as? CMAccelerometerData {
            self.accelerometerData = data
            updateAccelerometerLabels(data: data)
//            printAccelerometerData(data: data)
        }
    }

    @objc func updateGyroscopeData(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let data = notification.userInfo?["data"] as? CMGyroData {
            self.gyroscopeData = data
            updateGyroscopeLabels(data: data)
            printGyroscopeData(data: data)
        }
    }

    func updateAccelerometerLabels(data: CMAccelerometerData) {
        accelerationXLabel.text = String(format: "Acceleration X: %.2f", data.acceleration.x)
        accelerationYLabel.text = String(format: "Acceleration Y: %.2f", data.acceleration.y)
        accelerationZLabel.text = String(format: "Acceleration Z: %.2f", data.acceleration.z)
//        print("Accelerometer data updated: \(data)") // Print accelerometer update
    }

    func updateGyroscopeLabels(data: CMGyroData) {
        let xDegrees = radiansToDegrees(radians: data.rotationRate.x)
        let yDegrees = radiansToDegrees(radians: data.rotationRate.y)
        let zDegrees = radiansToDegrees(radians: data.rotationRate.z)

        rotationRateXLabel.text = String(format: "Rotation Rate X: %.2f°", xDegrees)
        rotationRateYLabel.text = String(format: "Rotation Rate Y: %.2f°", yDegrees)
        rotationRateZLabel.text = String(format: "Rotation Rate Z: %.2f°", zDegrees)
//        print("Gyroscope data updated: \(data)") // Print gyroscope update
    }

    func printAccelerometerData(data: CMAccelerometerData) {
        print(String(format: "Acceleration X: %.2f, Y: %.2f, Z: %.2f", data.acceleration.x, data.acceleration.y, data.acceleration.z))
        fflush(stdout) // Force flush the output buffer
    }

    func printGyroscopeData(data: CMGyroData) {
        let xDegrees = radiansToDegrees(radians: data.rotationRate.x)
        let yDegrees = radiansToDegrees(radians: data.rotationRate.y)
        let zDegrees = radiansToDegrees(radians: data.rotationRate.z)
        print(String(format: "Rotation Rate X: %.2f°, Y: %.2f°, Z: %.2f°", xDegrees, yDegrees, zDegrees))
        fflush(stdout) // Force flush the output buffer
    }

    func radiansToDegrees(radians: Double) -> Double {
        return radians * 180 / .pi
    }
}

# ViewControllerRepresentable.swift  
//
//  ViewControllerRepresentable.swift
//  CoreMotionDemo
//
//  Created by Julien Esposito on 6/18/24.
//

import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ViewControllerRepresentable: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewControllerType = ViewController

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> ViewController {
        return ViewController()
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: ViewController, context: Context) {
        // Update the view controller if needed
    }
}

